# Asp.Net Core: reset memoryCache for Integration Tests

Tags: c#, .net-core, integration-testing

I have created some basic Integration tests to call my Api and see if the permissions work properly. Now I have encountered a problem where running more all of the tests one of them fails - if run seperately though, it doesnt.

The reason is, that I am using IMemoryCache to store certain permissions once a user is logged in. But for my integration tests, the permissions are stored in the cache and when I try to change them for a test they are not refreshed.

In general, is there a way to invalidate the MemoryCache for every Integration test?

One of my integrationtest class basically does this:

```
    public IntegrationTest(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Namespace.Startup> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
        _client = _factory.CreateClient();

       // init the DB here etc... 

       var response = await _client.GetAsync("api/Some/Path");

       Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
    }
```

is there a way to tell the factory not to use a cache or use a mock cache oder something like that?

Edit:

The cache is setup in my startup.cs like this:

```
public class Startup
{

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMemoryCache();
        
        [...]
    }
    
}
```

And that is injected via DependenyInjection into my controllers, like this:

```
private IMemoryCache _cache;
private MemoryCacheEntryOptions _cacheOptions;
const int CACHE_LIFETIME_IN_DAYS = 7;

public SomeController(IMemoryCache cache) {
    _cache = cache;
    _cacheOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions().SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromDays(CACHE_LIFETIME_IN_DAYS));
}
```

and I'm using it in my controllers with `_cache.TryGetValue` and `_cache.Set`

Comment: Can you please show where and how the cache is set up an used?

Comment: Ok, I edited the initial question with info on how I set up the cache. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick fix you can try to do something like this:

```
var memoryCache = _factory.Services.GetService<IMemoryCache>() as MemoryCache;
memoryCache.Compact(1.0);
```

When you need to reset cache.

But I would recommend either to look into not sharing `_factory` between tests (though it can have some performance implications) or overwriting (like it is [done in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-5.0#customize-webapplicationfactory) with context) `IMemoryCache` to something that you can control outside as you need.

**UPD**

Since tests by default are not run in parrallel you can just manually register instance of `MemoryCache`. Something like this:

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup>
    : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
{
    internal readonly MemoryCache MemoryCache;
    public CustomWebApplicationFactory()
    {
        MemoryCache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
    }
    public void ClearCache() => MemoryCache.Compact(1.0);
    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(
                d => d.ServiceType ==
                     typeof(IMemoryCache));
            services.Remove(descriptor);
            services.AddSingleton<IMemoryCache>(MemoryCache);
        });
    }
}
```

And in test call `factory.ClearCache()`:

```
public void Test1()
{
    var factory = new CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup>();
    var memoryCache = factory.Services.GetService<IMemoryCache>() as MemoryCache;
    memoryCache.Set("test", "test");
    factory.ClearCache();
    Assert.IsFalse(memoryCache.TryGetValue("test", out var val));
}
```

If you will need to run tests with the same factory in parallel (though I would say better just create different factories) then you can create `IMemoryCache` implementation which will determine somehow (for example passing some specific header in client request) different test runs and return different instances of `MemoryCache` for them.

Comment: so how would you override the memoryCache as it is done in the docs? I tried but I dont see a way to do this

Comment: @Chi I would say in most cases just registering manualy created instance of `MemoryCache` should do.

Comment: @Chi was glad to help!